# Scaling and aligning a simplistic website with image content

Tags: css, css-grid

I am working on a simplistic website to show pictures in a single stream. To keep javascript to a minimum (just lazy loading), I only use a single relatively high-resolution version of each image and then rely on CSS to resize.

My question is how the rest of the website, at least the logo and the menu, can be best resized relative to the size of the images. After reading the [CSS grid guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-template-areas) I decided to use a grid with `grid-auto-flow: row`.

**The problem**: I want the logo to flush left with the left of the top image and the menu to flush right with the right of the top image (all horizontal images have the same width).

My current code either aligns logo and menu to the corners of the page (as with the code below) or centers both (if I move the `header` into the grid as first item)

```css
#main{
    height: max-content;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-row-gap: 8em;
    place-items: center center;
}

.photo_horizontal, .photo_vertical{
    object-fit: contain;
    height: auto;
}

.photo_horizontal{   
    width: 80vw;
    max-height: 80vh;
}

.photo_vertical{
    width: 60vw;
    max-height: 90vh;
}

/* THE HEADER */
header{
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}

#logo{
    width: 15em;
    justify-self: start;
}

header > div{
    margin: auto 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img id="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100/ff7f7f/333333?text=some%20website"/>
  <div>
    <a href="">menu1</a>
    <a href="">menu2</a>
  </div>
</header>
    
<div id="main">
    <img class="photo_horizontal" src="https://picsum.photos/3000/2000"/>
    <img class="photo_vertical" src="https://picsum.photos/2000/3000" />
    <img class="photo_vertical" src="https://picsum.photos/2000/3000" />
    <img class="photo_horizontal" src="https://picsum.photos/3000/2000" />
</div>
```

Is there an elegant way to resize images relative to the viewport but still align other content accordingly? I tried to pad logo and menu left/right but the necessary padding depends on the actual size of the image.

A pen can be found [here](https://codepen.io/f8low/pen/pojGdvX).

To clarify, [this is how it currently is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BtLy.jpg) and [this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVvPN.jpg).

Comment: I'm confused, is the question about the `navbar` or the `images` ? Why not simply use flexbox for the navbar https://jsfiddle.net/081bq97j/

Comment: It's about having `navbar` and `images` share the same width, but let the images dictate what that exact width is, their own based on height and width constraints. If that's easier with flexbox, I could switch...

Comment: It's just unclear to me what you're after

Comment: I added two screenshots to the end of my post.

Comment: The question isn't the place for posting answers, Remove it from the question post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers here I figured out a solution. There are three components:

1. As @Zohir Salak pointed out, much simpler CSS can be obtained using flexbox.
2. The `header` can be part of `main` even though this is not essential to the solution.
3. As @kmoser pointed out, the `max-height` constraint on images makes it hard to set a proper `max-width` constraint for the `header`, a problem that isn't solved by 1. and 2. yet. However, since all of my pictures are 3:2 ratio, a `max-height` constrained can be turned into a `max-width` constrained easily and then combined with a `min` via `max-width: min(80vw, 3 / 2 * 80vh);`.

```css
/* Nothing wrong with CSS grid, just Flexbox is simpler */

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

/* height being auto will keep the aspect ratio */
/* horizontal photo take full width */
.photo_horizontal {
    max-width: min(80vw, 3 / 2 * 80vh);
}


/* horizontal photo take some portion of width */
.photo_vertical {
    max-width: min(80vw, 2 / 3 * 80vh);
}

header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: min(80vw, 3 / 2 * 80vh);
}

#logo {
  width: 15em;
}

header>div {
  margin: auto 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
    
<div id="main">
      <header>
      <img id="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100/ff7f7f/333333?text=some%20website"/>
      <div>
        <a href="">menu1</a>
        <a href="">menu2</a>
      </div>
    </header> 

    <img class="photo_horizontal" src="https://picsum.photos/3000/2000"/>

    <img class="photo_vertical" src="https://picsum.photos/2000/3000" />
    
    <img class="photo_vertical" src="https://picsum.photos/2000/3000" />
    
    <img class="photo_horizontal" src="https://picsum.photos/3000/2000" />
</div>
```

Alternatively, see the same code in a pen [here](https://codepen.io/f8low/pen/BaobQvJ).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is setting `.photo_horizontal`'s `.max-height: 80vh;` causes it to not always honor the `width: 80vw;` which means the width of the `.photo_horizontal` is not easily calculated. That makes it difficult to make the `<header>` the same width.

You can do this:

```
header {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
}
```

But it only works if you also get rid of the `max-height: 80vh` rule for `.photo_horizontal`.

https://codepen.io/km0ser/pen/LYpqeYB

Comment: You're spot on, it's a delicate mix of constraints on the image width/height that cannot be replicated for the header. But the height constraint is a necessary one. Would anything change if I wrapped the `img`s in `div`s?

Comment: If you can wrap the images in `<div>`s and constrain the width/height of the `<div>`s then it should work, since the `<header>` would then reside in the first `<div>` and be constrained by its width.

Answer (score 0):

Why not include the header within `#main`

```css
/* Nothing wrong with CSS grid, just Flexbox is simpler */

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

/* height being auto will keep the aspect ratio */
/* horizontal photo take full width */
.photo_horizontal {
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* horizontal photo take some portion of width */
.photo_vertical {
  max-width: 80%;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#logo {
  width: 15em;
}

header>div {
  margin: auto 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <header>
    <img id="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100/ff7f7f/333333?text=some%20website" />
    <div>
      <a href="">menu1</a>
      <a href="">menu2</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <img class="photo_horizontal" src="https://picsum.photos/3000/2000" />
  <img class="photo_vertical" src="https://picsum.photos/2000/3000" />
  <img class="photo_vertical" src="https://picsum.photos/2000/3000" />
  <img class="photo_horizontal" src="https://picsum.photos/3000/2000" />
</div>
```

Comment: This plus an insight on the `max-height` issue let me come up with a solution. I edited the original post. Thanks a lot!